# Requested resource is not available when importing XML file with JSTL core in JSP file

Tags: xml, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm new to **Java EE** and i'm just at the beginning of learning XML library in **JSTL1.2 core**.

I'm trying to write a simple JSP file that reads an XML file and displays it.
The problem is that when i attempt to import an XML file, the server throws an exception concerning the line which imports the XML file saying:

> The requested resource (/test/document.xml) is not available.

Here's my JSP file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<c:import url="document.xml" varReader="documentReader" >
    <c:out value="${ documentReader }" />
</c:import>
</body>
</html>
```

The XML file **document.xml** is at my project's root.
Here's the exception thrown by the server Apache Tomcat 7.0.54 :

```
SEVERE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet default a lancé une exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: The requested resource (/test/document.xml) is not available
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:807)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:442)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:314)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireReader(ImportSupport.java:341)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doStartTag(ImportSupport.java:151)
    at org.apache.jsp.test_005fel_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fimport_005f0(test_005fel_jsp.java:109)
    at org.apache.jsp.test_005fel_jsp._jspService(test_005fel_jsp.java:77)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

avr. 01, 2015 8:38:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/test] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /test_el.jsp at line 9

6: <title>Création d'un client.</title>
7: </head>
8: <body>
9: <c:import url="document.xml" varReader="monReader" >
10:     <c:out value="${ monReader }" />
11: </c:import>
12: </body>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.io.FileNotFoundException: The requested resource (/test/document.xml) is not available
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:807)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:442)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:314)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireReader(ImportSupport.java:341)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doStartTag(ImportSupport.java:151)
    at org.apache.jsp.test_005fel_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fimport_005f0(test_005fel_jsp.java:109)
    at org.apache.jsp.test_005fel_jsp._jspService(test_005fel_jsp.java:77)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried something else to read the XML file using the absolute path of the file. This isn't a final solution but a partial solution which helps a little bit more.
I have given the following `value` to the attribute `url` :

```
<c:import url="file:/C:/PathToWS/WorkSpace/JavaEEProject/document.xml" varReader="xmlReader" >
<c:out value="${ xmlReader }" />
</c:import>
```

I've written `file` before the full path of the XML file to specify the protocol used in order to access a resource (file in this example), knowing that it could also be `http` or `ftp`.

Then, i can read and parse the XML file's content stored in `xmlReader`.

Of course, the XML file does not need to be in the java EE project's root, it can be wherever you want in the disk.